# Monitoring Screensaver activity fails on Windows 7

Tags: c++, winapi

Good afternoon, i have a section of code i am using to monitor screen saver activity in Windows XP onwards, this currently works correctly on all Windows OS's except for Windows 7, i am aware that certain screen saver parameters to the SystemParametersInfo function are not available in Windows 7 but thought that SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING was available, the code is as follows:

```
BOOL bScrnSvrRunning = FALSE;
BOOL bResult = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING, 0, &boolScreenSaverRunning, 0);
```

The function always returns true for bResult but bScrnSvrRunning is always false,

does anyone have any idea what might cause this?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong parameter "slot". Look closely at the declaration of `SystemParametersInfo`:

```
BOOL WINAPI SystemParametersInfo(
  __in     UINT uiAction,
  __in     UINT uiParam,
  __inout  PVOID pvParam,
  __in     UINT fWinIni
);
```

And let me quote the info for `SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING`:

> Determines whether a screen saver is currently running on the window station of the calling process. The pvParam parameter must point to a BOOL variable that receives TRUE if a screen saver is currently running, or FALSE otherwise.

`pvParam` is the one that recieves the info, so you must supply your bool in the `pvParam` parameter:

```
BOOL bScrnSvrRunning = FALSE;
BOOL bResult = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETSCREENSAVERRUNNING, 0, &boolScreenSaverRunning, 0);
```

Comment: i do, bScrnSvrRunning is passed into the pvParam slot

Comment: @user698391: Not in your code example, try copy/pasting mine instead of yours and see if it works.

Comment: aaah i see apologies, i am working on a seperate network and had to re-type my code, i added in an additional ",0" where there was not one, my code mirrors yours and as i said before, this works on all other OS's except Windows 7

Comment: @user698391: Then report the bug to Microsoft.

Comment: @user have you any idea how irritating it is to answer a question only to be told that the question asked was wrong due to inability to paste code?

Comment: i was not pasting code, i had to copy verbatim due to restricted network, i have apologised for this it was unintentional, so i fail to see how your comment adds value.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want **to monitor** the screen saver activity you can consider to use System Event Notification Service (SENS). The System Event Notification Service monitors and dispatches there, so it can notify your application about the starting (see [ISensLogon::StartScreenSaver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and stopping (see [ISensLogon::StopScreenSaver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) of the screen saver many events. An example how to use SENS you can find [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321381) (see also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301850.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480679.aspx)).